# Async vs then in Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

In the following code, I'm using a `Promise` with `.then()`, but it doesn't wait for `setTimeout()` as I'd expect.

Why does `async`/`await` wait for `setTimeout()` though? It looks like `await` waits for the `Promise` to resolve, but `.then()` doesn't. Can someone please provide some details?

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('hello');
}

function myPromiseFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('hey');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

myPromiseFunction().then(hello());  // Prints 'hello' then 'hey'

async function myAsyncFunction() {
  await myPromiseFunction();
  hello();
}

myAsyncFunction();  // Prints 'hey' then 'hello'
```

Comment: `.then(hello)` (note the removal of immediate invocation)

Comment: `foo(bar())` always calls `bar` *first* and passes its return value to `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myPromiseFunction().then(hello())` uses the result of calling `hello()` as the callback to `.then()`. If you wish to use `hello()` as the callback function itself, use either of these syntaxes:

```js
myPromiseFunction().then(() => hello());
```

```js
myPromiseFunction().then(hello);
```

Note that the second syntax silently passes a parameter to `hello()` - the value resolved by the `Promise`. In your example this isn’t a problem (since `hello()` doesn’t check use its arguments at all), but it may be the cause of gotchas down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
myPromiseFunction().then(()=>hello())
```

You are calling a function, not providing a function to call.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking hello with ()

```
.then(hello());
```

hello is called and returns void, you are then passing void into the then as the callback function.